# Codeigniter Htaccess configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to configure my htaccess file such when i type the folder name in small case or in upper case it will redirect to the same folder.

Currently i have my file as :

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /ABC/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

The problem is when i try to access my controller giving the folder name in small case , it cannot find the controller.

That is if i try something as `abc/contrller_name/controller_function`
 it says path no found.
 Note:Working on Windows System and using XAMPP

Comment: I believe converting path's to controllers/folder names is more a job for php then for apache imo

Answer (score 1):

**In .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**In config.php (`application/config`)**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'; # set this to prevent HOST Injectio.
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure for Ubuntu/Debian systems.

1. From the command line, type sudo su to get root privileges.
2. nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/speling.conf
3. Type CheckSpelling on and hit ctrl-x, y to exit and save the file.
4. type a2enmod and then speling and hit enter.
5. type /etc/init.d/apache2 reload to reload apache.
6. Mistype a url to test it.

Source [making-apache-case-insensitive](https://keystoneit.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/making-apache-case-insensitive/)

According to Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/platform/windows.html), it is not possible, because case insensitivity is embedded in Windows OS. But you can "reverse the problem" and turn the Apache server under Linux/Unix being case insensitive. Just add the following directives to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lowercase:$1} [R,L]
```

Comment: @Gautam: Updated answer. Not sure though. Check if it works.

Comment: @Gautam: It should redirect your urls and make it as lowercase. Restart your apache after making changes.

Comment: Can u merge your set of lines in my code. Cause i'm weak in server programming. that would be a great help

Comment: @Gautam: Check if it works. I had hands on it long back.

Comment: not working it gives me a server error. anyways thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Modify **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|FolderName1|uploaded|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foldername/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Note: foldername is `htdocs path`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```